# Google Analytics - Find most popular site directories

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to be able to track the most popular directories on my site. The site is split as follows:

- [www.sitename.com/directoryA](http://www.sitename.com/directoryA)
- [www.sitename.com/directoryB](http://www.sitename.com/directoryB)
- [www.sitename.com/directoryC](http://www.sitename.com/directoryC)

Each directory has thousands of pages recording views underneath it e.g.

- [www.sitename.com/directoryA/page1](http://www.sitename.com/directoryA/page1)
- [www.sitename.com/directoryA/page2](http://www.sitename.com/directoryA/page2)
- [www.sitename.com/directoryA/page3](http://www.sitename.com/directoryA/page3)

What I would like to is roll up the views from all the pages to create a table of my my popular directories (there are thousands on the site)

How can I do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DalmTo To solve this, you need regex and some programming in DataStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field in DataStudio with this regex:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'(/[^/]+)')
```

This way, you can use this new field to group your counters based on part of the URL.

If you need to analyze other levels, just adjust the regex, repeating `/[^/]+`:

- 1st level (/path1): `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'(/[^/]+)')`
- 2nd level (/path1/path2): `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'(/[^/]+/[^/]+)')`
- 3rd level (/path1/path2/path3): `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'(/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)')`
- ...

Comment: Cheers, that looks to have worked. Quick follow up. Some of the URLs have a random extra level in that serves no purpose, but impacts the results.

e.g. sitename/thesite/path1 is the same as
sitename/path1

Is there a way to account for that?

Comment: Sure, it is all a matter of writing the correct regex to group similar URLs over the same name. I suggest you to read about regular expressions. There are lots of good tutorials around the web (check https://www.regular-expressions.info/). About your specific case, try this: `'(?:/thesite)?(/[^/]+)'`. It says "ignore paths starting with '/thesite', if they exist".