# Google Analytics / Data Studio - Remove string from the middle of a URL before processing data

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a website with thousands of directories which I am trying to find out which are the most popular through using the following field

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'(/[^/]+)')
```

This is working great following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334328/google-analytics-find-most-popular-site-directories), however there is a random extra string in the URL which is impacting the figures.

e.g

- sitename.com/directoryA returns the same page as
- sitename.com/randomstring/directoryA

This means that when I run my field some of the views that should be attributed to the /directoryA/ are being attributed to /randomstring and my table reports as follows:

1. /randomstring = 1,000 views
2. directoryA = 800 views
3. directoryB = 850 views
4. ...

Does anyone know how to clean the data in Google Data studio so that /randomstring is removed from the URLs before I run my REGEXP_EXTRACT code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If it is random, how can you differentiate it from `directoryA` and `directoryB`? What makes `directoryA` not random?

Comment: Bad choice of words. The string isn't random, is the same every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional details provided by the Original Poster (Benjamin Heap) in the [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349740/google-analytics-data-studio-remove-string-from-the-middle-of-a-url-before-p#comment117374457_66349740):

> The string isn't random, is the same every time

One approach is to use a [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function before the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487), thus, the below will do the trick (replace `/randomstring` with the actual string):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(Page, "(/randomstring)", ""), "(/[^/]+)")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5285fbe4-4939-4282-9496-94e3f01061a6) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]